# External keyboard repeats keypresses - lliiikkkkeee tttthhhhiiiiis

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, keyboard, uefi

Whenever I press a button with an external USB keyboard, they get pressed multiple times (like in the title). Internal keyboard on my Lenovo T460s works fine.

- Live distro booted from USB: same problem
- Kernels tested: 4.8.4, currently on 4.10.0-041000-generic
- updated Lenovo BIOS/UEFI (1.22)
- Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS
- Keyboard: Coolermaster MasterKeys S (seemed to work for others on Linux)
- other USB keyboard (Logitech) works fine
- Tried out all USB ports (dock, directly)
- It worked when I plugged in the keyboard the **very first time**.
- Set the keyboard settings to disable keyboard repeats with no success
- When typing very fast with a single click, it enters only a single character

---

The one without a manufacturer is the keyboard:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f2:b52c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2516:003c 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 17ef:100f Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ dmesg
[   43.169824] usb 1-4.4.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   43.269936] usb 1-4.4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2516, idProduct=003c
[   43.269937] usb 1-4.4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   43.269938] usb 1-4.4.1: Product: MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB
[   43.269939] usb 1-4.4.1: Manufacturer: Cooler Master Technology Inc.
[   43.790796] input: Cooler Master Technology Inc. MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4.1/1-4.4.1:1.0/0003:2516:003C.0005/input/input19
[   43.854216] hid-generic 0003:2516:003C.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Cooler Master Technology Inc. MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4.1/input0
[   43.854793] hid-generic 0003:2516:003C.0006: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Cooler Master Technology Inc. MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4.1/input1
[   43.855475] input: Cooler Master Technology Inc. MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4.1/1-4.4.1:1.2/0003:2516:003C.0007/input/input20
[   43.913950] hid-generic 0003:2516:003C.0007: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Cooler Master Technology Inc. MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4.1/input2
```

---

```
$ xinput list
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cooler Master Technology Inc. MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB   id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cooler Master Technology Inc. MASTERKEYS PRO S with intelligent RGB   id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Is it normal to show up twice in `dmesg` and `xinput` but not fully in `lsusb`? Can it be that the device was "installed" twice, so the "first" device and the "second" device interfer? Please help me find the cause, I'm losing my mind... Happy to provide more logs.

Comment: I wish I had the same setup as you, it would be easier to come up with a better answer.  But I just read that it repeats even when booted to a live distro.  Have you tried adjusting the Repeat Rate keys with the FN+F5 - F8?

Comment: @Terrance - yes I tried it, but I thought that is just the repeat rate of LEDs. Maybe I need to try a firmware update and install the profiling software on a Windows computer. The only logical explanation to me is that it installed the keyboard twice, so it shoots `KeyPressed` for both but can only process until the second device has processed `KeyReleased` as well. Isn't it strange that two keyboards are installed as the logs say?

Comment: @Terrance oh dear... you are probably right, need to test this later http://community.coolermaster.com/topic/20563-masterkeys-keys-repeating/

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: Thanks!! For reference if anyone else has the issue: The manual does not tell how to reset properly, you have to hold FN+E for some seconds http://community.coolermaster.com/topic/16653-masterkeys-pro-l-and-s-mega-thread/?do=findComment&comment=129604

Comment: That is good to know.  You should write it as an answer.  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue of Ubuntu or the OS, a simple keyboard reset does the trick (the manual does not tell how to reset properly) See [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170723082731/http://community.coolermaster.com/topic/16653-masterkeys-pro-l-and-s-mega-thread/?page=6#comment-129604) to reset the keyboard (formatting own):

> Option 1:
>
> - unlug the keyboard
> - press FN+Right Alt
> - replug the keyboard back in (while keeping FN+Right Alt pressed)
>
> Ã  This option should make the keyboard go back to factory
> settings/demo mode.
>
> Option 2:
>
> - keep the keyboard plugged in to the PC
> - Press FN+E for about 3 to 5 seconds
>
> Ã  This option will clear the keyboards onboard memory

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a wireless logitech keyboard designed for mac. I tried both Option 1 and Option 2, and it solved my problem of double typing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a USB keyboard, especially an old one, try plugging it into a USB 2.0 socket instead of a USB 3.0 socket.
2. If only a few keys are sticking or repeating, try carefully cleaning around those keys.
3. Increase the repeat delay. In Ubuntu 18.04 and later go to Settings -> *Universal Access* -> click *Repeat Keys*. Increase the repeat delay by moving the Delay slider to the right.

   [image]
   <sup>**Repeat Keys settings in Ubuntu 18.04**</sup>
4. As a side note, if one of the keys on a keyboard is registering a keystroke only intermittently, carefully remove the top part of the key with the letter from the keyboard, and if the spring inside is broken snip a length of coiled spring from inside a pen and replace the old spring under the key with a new one. Try a few different lengths of spring until you find the length that produces the same spring action as all the other keys, otherwise the key will either stick or repeat when it is pressed.